# Parse XMLHttpRequest.responseText with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

After performing XMLHttpRequest how can I parse responseText with jquery?
I tried

> var parsed = $.parseHTML(data);

but the result is DOM array and I can not select anything by 
`$(parsed).find('#myIDobject')` or so.

Comment: You can find your answer [here][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811279/convert-string-into-jquery-object-and-select-inner-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if not a collection of DOM elements, then what did you expect?

If the element you're trying to "find" is at root level, you'll need to use filter:

```
var parsed  = $.parseHTML(data); 

var element = $(parsed).filter('#myIDobject');
```

and to avoid the issue completely, you can do:

```
var parsed  = $.parseHTML(data); 

parsed = $('<div />').append(parsed);

parsed.find('#anything');
```

Comment: Why cant I use find() directly on `parsed`?

Comment: `$.parseHTML()` returns an  array of dom nodes, not a jquery object.

Comment: @ask filter is required only if the element you are looking for is a top level element in the dom collection. `.find` only looks at descendants of the currently selected elements, and when you do `$(parsed)`, you're selecting all the top level elements contained within `parsed`.

Comment: How can I parse reply string into a jquery object then? I can not find required element nor by `find()` nor by `filter()` function

Comment: @Ask the updated answer should answer your question.