# Extracting data from an HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I have this piece of HTML code as a string stored in a variable.

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size: small;font-family: comic sans ms', sans-serif;">
        <strong>
            word1&nbsp;
            <span style="line-height: 1.5;">
                word2&nbsp;
            </span>
            <span style="line-height: 1.5;">
                word3&nbsp;
            </span>
            <span style="line-height:1.5;"></span>
        </strong>
    </span>
</p>
```

I want only to extract `word1&nbsp;`, `word2&nbsp;` and `word3&nbsp;`. How can I do it in an easiest and time efficient way?

I was thinking the character `>` that was not preceded immediately by `<` can be a index where I can start extracting my data.

Comment: It's not quite regex, but `document.querySelector('p').innerText.split(' ')` will extract the information, more or less.

Comment: @litel --> The HTML Code above was a string stored in a variable. How will I do it in my case?

Comment: What language are you extracting the variable from? How are you getting the variable?

Comment: The string was  stored in the database for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var html = '<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size: small;font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;">
        <strong>
            alyssa&nbsp;
            <span style="line-height: 1.5;">
                enganio&nbsp;
            </span>
            <span style="line-height: 1.5;">
                gono&nbsp;
            </span>
            <span style="line-height:1.5;"></span>
        </strong>
    </span>
</p>';
    var values = $(html).find('p strong').text().split(' ');
```

or

```
var v =[];
v.push($(html).find('p strong').clone().find('span').remove().end().text());
$(html).find('p strong span').each(function(i,val) {
if($.trim($(val).text()).length>0)
v.push($(val).text())
});
console.log(v);
```

Comment: The HTML Code above was a string stored in a variable. How will I do it in my case?

Comment: Assuming code is in myhtml variable, just replace $('p strong') with $(myhtml).find('p strong') and $('p strong span') with $(myhtml).find('p strong span'). (has now been fixed in the reply)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can fetch easily

lets try this one:-

```
$('p').text();
```

it will return the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or also used to set the text contents of the matched elements.

Comment: The HTML Code above was a string stored in a variable. How will I do it in my case?

Comment: You can add that code in some where in Div and set display property "none" and do like $('p').text().trim().split("\xa0");

Answer (score 1):

Since you used regex tag I will post a solution with regex.

```
var re = /\w+&nbsp;/g;
var results = html.match(re);
```

Then you can access the results from "results" array.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this, it will return you all text inside p tag - `"alyssa&nbsp; , enganio&nbsp; , gono&nbsp;"`:

```
alert($("p").text());
```

Comment: The HTML Code above was a string stored in a variable. How will I do it in my case?

Comment: add that html in hidden div in page, process above line  and as you get result just remove that hidden div

Comment: ok then after getting 'alyssa enganio gono' you can just split them using string.split(" "). and you can get them seperated

Comment: No I have to preserved the blank spaces within the span, because it's part of the text format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want fetch text of tag without text of children.

So just see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

This code:

```
 console.log($("strong").clone().children().remove().end().text());
```

And to changing a string to jQuery object see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811279/convert-string-into-jquery-object-and-select-inner-element)

This code:

```
var element = $('<div id="a1"></div><div id="a3"></div>');
```